# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp accounts.google.com :443: getsockopt: operation timed out

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get the pods list from the gcloud project.

The gcloud project I've created in the `gcp` using different laptop.
Now I'm using different machine but logged into same `gcp` account and using same project.

When I run the command `kubectl get pods` I get the below error.

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp a.b.c.d:443: getsockopt: operation timed out
```

I tried to add an argument `--verbose`  but that doesn't seems to be valid.

How can I further proceed in resolving this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster-name` will log you into your cluster locally

From the docs: 
"updates a kubeconfig file with appropriate credentials and endpoint information to point kubectl at a specific cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine." - [src](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials)

Comment: Chainlink - this does resolve the error and now I'm able to see the `kubectl get pods` results. Can you please let me know what caused the issue earlier?